# Define a grammar from the alphabet $\{ a, b \}$ which accepts the string $w$ where $\#_{w(b)} \leq \#_{w(a)} \leq 2 \#_{w(b)}$

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Given the following problem:

> Define a grammar that only generates all the strings from the language of the alphabet $\sum = \{ a, b \}$ such that the number of letters **a** is more than or equal to the number of letters **b** and less than or equal to double the number of letters **b**.

I am not sure how to proceed with these types of problems where I required to maintain a count and a limit of the number of each character in the string.

How do go about resolving such a problem?